# Android-Get Position Pointer From Using Geocoder

Tags: android

Below is my code. For some address the below code works in Android Device API level-8.But for some address the value of address is returned as [].BUt I am not getting such problem while calling same server from iphone.

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> address = geocoder.getFromLocationName(MAPADDRESS, 1);
```

How to resolve this issue in android device.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are requesting only one address while querying

```
List<Address> address = geocoder.getFromLocationName(MAPADDRESS, 1);
```

Android will try to find only one address in this case.You should raise this 2 or 3.

Maybe at second or third position you will get sucess.

Change it to

```
List<Address> address = geocoder.getFromLocationName(MAPADDRESS, 3);
```

Comment: Thank you Vipul for ur answer.I wll try with this.

Comment: I tried with following:

List<Address> address = geocoder.getFromLocationName(MAPADDRESS, 3) and 
List<Address> address = geocoder.getFromLocationName(MAPADDRESS, 15) 

but still it is showing adress.size() = 0.

Comment: Can you paste your code here.That would help to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following method... while calling give the string input

```
 public static JSONObject getLocationInfo(String address) {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            try {

            address = address.replaceAll(" ","%20");    

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + address + "&sensor=false");
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response;
            stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();


                response = client.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
                int b;
                while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
                    stringBuilder.append((char) b);
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }




            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return jsonObject;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much all for replying.Thank you Rajesh.It worked.

Comment: glad to hear. it is helped you a lot know .. why didnt  you choose this as accpted answer.?

Comment: Actually I am new to this so did not know.From next time I will do for sure.Thanks.

Comment: no problem if you are having one click option in right corner of my answer means do it else leave it ..